# Ruby - remove part of the text

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a text similar to this:

```
<p>some text ...</p><p>The post <a href="http://url_address/">text...</a> appeared first on <a href="http://url_address">some another text</a>.</p>
```

I need to remove everything from `<p>The post`, so the results would be:

```
<p>some text ...</p>
```

I am trying ot do that this way:

```
text.sub!(/^<p>The post/, '')
```

But it returns just an empty string... how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. It matches every `<p>The post` that is in the beginning of the string. You want the opposite: match from its position to the end of the string. Check this out.

```
s = '<p>some text ...</p><p>The post <a href="http://url_address/">text...</a> appeared first on <a href="http://url_address">some another text</a>.</p>'

s.sub(/<p>The\spost.*$/, '') # => "<p>some text ...</p>"
```

Answer (score 2):

'^' is matching the beginning of the whole string. try doing

```
text.sub!(/<p>The post/, '')
```

**EDIT** just read it more carefully...

```
text.sub!(/<p>The post.*$/, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have specified `^`, which matches the beginning of a string. You should do

```
text.sub!(/<p>The post.*$/, '')
```

Play with this in http://rubular.com/r/c91EbHN0Af